# Как посчитать количество в dataframe, по списку, а потом дополнить недостающими

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть список в нём данные и список частот в диапозоне от 233 до 253

```
Ячейка Частота 
203     233
203     234
203     236
203     239
203     240
205     235
205     239
205     240
```

Для каждой ячейки должно быть 20 частот, как посчитать сколько частот сейчас уже занято по списку, сколько можно дописать и как их дописать в список, дополнив то, что сейчас уже есть?

Сам пробовал, но смог только посчитать сколько сейчас занято и то не совсем правильным способом:

```
df = df.groupby(['CELL']).size().reset_index(name='CountUsed')
print (df)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе пример выходного (ожидаемого) датасета

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Количество записей в каждой ячейке:

```
In [106]: res = df.groupby("Ячейка")["Частота"].size().reset_index(name="Count")

In [107]: res
Out[107]:
   Ячейка  Count
0     203      5
1     205      3
```

или:

```
In [111]: df["Ячейка"].value_counts().rename_axis("Ячейка").reset_index(name="Count")
Out[111]:
   Ячейка  Count
0     203      5
1     205      3
```

PS дополните вопрос о дополнении данных показательным примером данных, которые вы хотите получить на выходе для того чтобы получить получить полноценный ответ...